# Knockout - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Level'

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm have real issues understanding why this simple test throw a runtime error.

I've got a knockout computed property 'Level' as part of my FilterClause object, I've followed the documentation to the letter, yet it still throws the runtime error...

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Level'
```

I think it has something to do with the object not being instantiated at the time of construction where the computed property function is declared. But it follows, or at least seems to follow the knockout documentation to the letter.

Confused!!

Here's my code:

```
var FilterClause = function (json, parent) {
    this.FilterClauseID = ko.observable();
    this.Type = ko.observable();
    this.Left = ko.observable();
    this.Right = ko.observable();
    this.ParentID = ko.observable();
    this.Parent = ko.observable(parent);
    this.Children = ko.observableArray();
    this.Level = ko.observable(0);

    // computed
    this.Padding = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.Level().ToString() + "px";
    });

    var mapping = {
        'Children': {
            create: function (args) {
                return new FilterClause(args.data, this);
            }
        },
        'ignore': ["Parent"]
    };

    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping, this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bajGm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue with context inside computed. There are 2 ways to fix error. First is to add this as second parameter to computed:

```
this.Padding = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.Level().ToString() + "px";
}, this);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bajGm/1/

Or second - assign this to variable:

```
var self = this;
self.FilterClauseID = ko.observable();
self.Type = ko.observable();
self.Left = ko.observable();
self.Right = ko.observable();
self.ParentID = ko.observable();
self.Parent = ko.observable(parent);
self.Children = ko.observableArray();
self.Level = ko.observable(0);

// computed
self.Padding = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.Level().toString() + "px";
})
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bajGm/3/

Read carefully this article http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html. It explains in details root cause of your issue.

Comment: Sweet!! I see the issue now. Thank you very much. My fault for not reading the docs completely. So from an experienced knockout/javascript programmer, which of the two working examples is more preferable? Example 'one' is much more tidy looking, but example 'two' is clearer, but could be more prone to mistakes creeping in. I guess personal choice?

Comment: Another question @Artem Vyshniakov, how would you get the 'Level' value from the parent if that is also in the construction state?

Comment: I prefer the second way. Sorry didn't your question.

Comment: Sorry @Artem Vyshniakov, did't really explain myself very well, see your updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/bajGm/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/bajGm/6/), basically I'm trying to get and use a value from a parent item.

Comment: It is not the best solution to store parent in your vm. You can use existing $parent object in the view instead of adding it to vm. Read this article - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Answer (score 1):

In the computed Padding, this refers to window.

To avoid this you should create a self private field :

```
var self = this;
self.FilterClauseID = ko.observable();
self.Type = ko.observable();
self.Left = ko.observable();
self.Right = ko.observable();
self.ParentID = ko.observable();
self.Parent = ko.observable(parent);
self.Children = ko.observableArray();
self.Level = ko.observable(0);

// computed
this.Padding = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.Level().toString() + "px";
});
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bajGm/5/)